# finding number of the first d zeroes in a hash object using loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to determine security level "d" by counting the number of the first d 0's in a hash string using SHA256 (I defined **c_hash(mystring,sha256)** to do that).
I used **generate_name** function that generate a random first name with 3-6 letters and family name with 4-8 letters. Here is my code:

```
def d_security(d):
   t0 = time.clock()
   cnt = 0
   while cnt != d:
       obj = generate_name()
       hash_obj = c_hash(obj,sha256)
       if hash_obj[:d] == d*"0":
           cnt+=1
   t1 = time.clock()
   print(t1-t0)
   return None
```

for d = 5, it takes over 2min find a string that matches the security level. Any suggestion on how to make this run faster using another loop?

Comment: It's too slow to do that with CPUs, even GPUs, now you'll need a farm of [ASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-specific_integrated_circuit)s.

Answer (score 0):

1. `d*"0"` is being recalculated everytime despite being constant. Maybe calculate it and assign it to another variable BEFORE the while loop will help.
2. If your code is running slowly it's not mainly because of the loop.  Generating names and hashes should take the majority of run time. So either:

   2a. Generate shorter names, or

   2b. If the has function allows, re-design your hash generator `c_hash` to return only the first `d` digits of the hash value. You only need those digits after all, calculating the whole hash values takes time.

Comment: I'm not allowed to change the name generator but I can change the `c_hash`. Just for clarification, is there a way to return the first d digits of the hash value without `[:d]`? I'm using this: `hash_object = function(mystring.encode()) , return(hash_object.hexdigest())`

Comment: Your question is how to speed up your code, the answer is to modify your hash function. But how to do that, is another bigger question, and requires you to post how you implemented your hash function, which means you should ask that in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate d*"0" only once by putting it in the top of the function.
Also, use startswith instead of using a slice. Effectively giving you:

```
def d_security(d):
   expected = d*"0"
   t0 = time.clock()
   cnt = 0
   while cnt != d:
       obj = generate_name()
       hash_obj = c_hash(obj,sha256)
       if hash_obj.startswith(expected):
           cnt+=1
   t1 = time.clock()
   print(t1-t0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately it didn't change much, I was thinking of finding a way that `c_hash` can only return the first `d` digits instead of the whole hash string.